# How can I validate this multistep form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I want to validate step number 6. user can not go the next step until filling the current step.  That means when users click continues without filling the date of the birth field there will appear a warning like ''this field is required''.

when I try to validate but it did not work. without validating the current step the user can go the next step easily.

```
 <!-- Step 1 -->
            <div id="step-1" class="p-5 lg animated">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">What Vehicle Would You Like?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row lg">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="1" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked">
                                        <input name="vehicle" value="Car" type="checkbox" id="car" checked>
                                        <label class="checkbox-label" for="car">
                                            <img src="images/car-1.jpg" alt="Car">

                                            <div class="img-title">Car</div>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="1" class="custom-box">
                                        <input name="vehicle" value="Suv" type="checkbox" id="bus">
                                        <label class="checkbox-label" for="bus">
                                            <img src="images/van-1.jpg" alt="Sub">
                                            <div class="img-title">SUV</div>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="1" class="custom-box">
                                        <input name="vehicle" value="Motorbike" type="checkbox" id="bike">
                                        <label class="checkbox-label" for="bike">
                                            <img src="images/bike-1.jpg" alt="Bike">

                                            <div class="img-title">Motorbike</div>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="2" class="app-btn next" onclick="what_vehicle()">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    Don’t worry, you can change your mind about the kind of vehicle you want at any time.
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Step 2 -->
            <div id="step-2" class="p-5 md animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">What Is Your Monthly Budget?</h3>

                    <div class="app-row md">

                        <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                            <div class="app-list cols2">
                                <div data-step="2" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked" data-value="Under £150/month">
                                    <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                        <input type="radio" id="budget1" name="budget" value="Under £150/month" checked>
                                        <label for="budget1">Under £150/month</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="app-list cols2">
                                <div data-step="2" class="custom-box" data-value="Under £150 - £250/month">
                                    <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                        <input class='radio' type="radio" id="budget2" name="budget" value="Under £150 - £250/month">
                                        <label for="budget2">Under £150 - £250/month</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="app-list cols2">
                                <div data-step="2" class="custom-box" data-value="Under £251 - £350/month">
                                    <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                        <input class='radio' type="radio" id="budget3" name="budget" value="Under £251 - £350/month">
                                        <label for="budget3">Under £251 - £350/month</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="app-list cols2">
                                <div data-step="2" class="custom-box" data-value="Over £350/month">
                                    <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                        <input class='radio' type="radio" id="budget4" name="budget" value="Over £350/month">
                                        <label for="budget4">Over £350/month</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="1" class="app-btn prev">Previous</button>
                    <button data-step="3" class="app-btn next" id="p_pusher2_3">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    Your desired monthly budget can help us better determine an appropriate loan program for you
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 3 -->
            <div id="step-3" class="p-5 animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">Are You Currently Driving a Vehicle?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="3" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked" data-value="No">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="driveVehicle1" name="driveVehicle" value="No" checked>
                                            <label for="driveVehicle1">No</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="3" class="custom-box" data-value="Yes, I want to keep it">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="driveVehicle2" name="driveVehicle" value=" Yes, I want to keep it">
                                            <label for="driveVehicle2"> Yes, I want to keep it</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="3" class="custom-box" data-value="Yes, I want to trade it in">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="driveVehicle3" name="driveVehicle" value=" Yes, I want to trade it in">
                                            <label for="driveVehicle3"> Yes, I want to trade it in</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="2" class="app-btn prev" id="p_pusher3_2">Previous</button>
                    <button data-step="4" class="app-btn next">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    We can get you pre-approved with or without a trade in.
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 4 -->
            <div id="step-4" class="p-5 animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">What Is Your Estimated Credit Rating?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked" data-value="Good">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="creditRating" value="Good" checked>
                                            <label for="rating1">Good</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box" data-value="Fair">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="creditRating" value="Fair">
                                            <label for="rating2">Fair</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box" data-value="Poor">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="creditRating" value="Poor">
                                            <label for="rating3">Poor</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box" data-value="Very Poor">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="creditRating" value="Very Poor">
                                            <label for="rating4">Very Poor</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box" data-value="Current Bankcruptcy">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="creditRating" value="Current Bankcruptcy">
                                            <label for="rating5">Current Bankcruptcy</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="4" class="custom-box" data-value="No Credit">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="rating6" name="creditRating" value="No Credit">
                                            <label for="rating6">No Credit</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="3" class="app-btn prev">Previous</button>
                    <button data-step="5" class="app-btn next">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    Your estimated credit rating helps us determined the appropriate loan program for you.
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 5 -->
            <div id="step-5" class="p-5 md animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">Are You Interested In No Deposit Options?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="5" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked" data-value="Yes">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="depositOption1" name="depositOption" value="Yes" checked>
                                            <label for="depositOption1">Yes</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="5" class="custom-box" data-value="No">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="depositOption2" name="depositOption" value="No">
                                            <label for="depositOption2">No</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="4" class="app-btn prev">Previous</button>
                    <button data-step="6" class="app-btn next">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    We have no deposit options available, making it even easier for you to get the car you want.
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 6 -->
            <div id="step-6" class="p-5 animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">Are You Old Enough to Get Financing?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list text-center">
                                    <label class="label-text">Date of Birth</label><span id="error" style="color: red;"></span>
                                    <div data-step="6" class="custom-box app-input-container dob">
                                        <input name="dob" type="date" id="dob" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY">
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="app-input-hint">DD / MM / YYYY</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="5" class="app-btn prev">Previous</button>
                   <button data-step="7" class="app-btn next" id="dateOfBirthValidation" disabled>Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    To be eligible to submit an application, you must be 18 or older.
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 7 -->
            <div id="step-7" class="p-5 animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">Where Are You Looking for a Vehicle?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list text-center">
                                    <label class="label-text">Home Address<span id="erroraddress" style="color: red;"></span></label>
                                    <div data-step="7" class="custom-box app-input-container home">
                                        <input type="text" name="homeaddress" id="search_input" placeholder="Begin Typing Adress Here">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="latitude_input" />
                                        <input type="hidden" id="longitude_input" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-selection-message" id="addressSelectionMessage">
                        <p>The Address you have selected is: </p>
                        <p class="message" id="addrMessage"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="6" class="app-btn prev" id="p_pusher7_6">Previous</button>
                    <a href="#cngpopup" rel="modal:open"><button data-step="8" class="app-btn app-btn next mt-5" id="lookingVehicle">Continue</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    Available programs vary based on where you live. Please help us find the most convenient option for you by entering your home mailing address above.
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Step 8 -->
            <div id="step-8" class="p-5 animated slideInRight" style="display: none;">
                <div class="app-inner">
                    <h3 class="mb-5">What Is Your Residential Status?</h3>
                    <div class="app-row">
                        <div class="app-list-wrap">
                            <div class="app-list-wrap-inner">
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box custom-box-clicked" data-value="Homeowner">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus1" name="resiStatus1" value="Homeowner" checked>
                                            <label for="resiStatus1">Homeowner</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Private Tenant (Furnished)">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus2" name="resiStatus1" value="Private Tenant (Furnished)">
                                            <label for="resiStatus2">Private Tenant (Furnished)</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Private Tenant (Unfurnished)">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus3" name="resiStatus1" value="Private Tenant (Unfurnished)">
                                            <label for="resiStatus3">Private Tenant (Unfurnished)</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Council Tenant">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus4" name="resiStatus1" value="Council Tenant">
                                            <label for="resiStatus4">Council Tenant</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Living With Parents">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus5" name="resiStatus1" value="Living With Parents">
                                            <label for="resiStatus5">Living With Parents</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Living With Family">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus6" name="resiStatus1" value="Living With Family">
                                            <label for="resiStatus6">Living With Family</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Joint Owner">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus7" name="resiStatus1" value="Joint Owner">
                                            <label for="resiStatus7">Joint Owner</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="app-list cols3">
                                    <div data-step="8" class="custom-box " data-value="Other">
                                        <div class="radio-toolbar">
                                            <input type="radio" id="resiStatus8" name="resiStatus1" value="Other">
                                            <label for="resiStatus8">Other</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-btn-wrap">
                    <button data-step="7" class="app-btn prev">Previous</button>
                    <button data-step="9" class="app-btn app-btn next mt-5">Continue</button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-btm-text">
                    Your address details help us determine a suitable budget and loan amount for you.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my jquery for the next and previous step and progress bar working code.

```
  $('.next').click(function () {
      var pgrbar = $('.progress-bar').width();
      var nextStep = $(this).data('step');
      var currentStep = nextStep - 1;
      var pgrbar = nextStep * 5.56;
      $('.progress-bar').width(pgrbar + '%');

      $('#step-' + currentStep).hide();

      $('#step-' + nextStep).show();
      $('#step-' + nextStep).removeClass("slideInLeft").addClass("slideInRight");
  });

  $('.prev').click(function () {
      var pgrbar = $('.progress-bar').width();
      var prevStep = $(this).data('step');
      var currentStep = prevStep + 1;
      var pgrbar = prevStep * 5.56;
      $('.progress-bar').width(pgrbar + '%');
      $('#step-' + currentStep).hide();
      $('#step-' + prevStep).show();
      $('#step-' + prevStep).removeClass("slideInRight").addClass("slideInLeft");
  });
```

Comment: You can try use php sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that we will use to validate that specific step, I made `validateStep(currentStep)`. `currentStep` contains the index or number of the current step.

Since you already assigned the steps a specific ID, We will then access the current step by `var targetStep = "#step-" + currentStep;`.

Then from their we will `.find()` all the inputs and check if there is a null or empty value. ***If there is an empty value, alert and return false which will not proceed to the next step.***

Use the script below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validateStep(currentStep) {
    var validate = true;
    var targetStep = "#step-" + currentStep;

    $(targetStep).find("input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).val() == null) {
        alert($(this).attr("name") + " is required.");
        validate = false;
      }
    })

    return validate;
  }

  $('.next').click(function() {
    var pgrbar = $('.progress-bar').width();
    var nextStep = $(this).data('step');
    var currentStep = nextStep - 1;
    var pgrbar = nextStep * 5.56;
    $('.progress-bar').width(pgrbar + '%');

    if (validateStep(currentStep)) {
      $('#step-' + currentStep).hide();
      $('#step-' + nextStep).show();
      $('#step-' + nextStep).removeClass("slideInLeft").addClass("slideInRight");
    }


  });

  $('.prev').click(function() {
    var pgrbar = $('.progress-bar').width();
    var prevStep = $(this).data('step');
    var currentStep = prevStep + 1;
    var pgrbar = prevStep * 5.56;
    $('.progress-bar').width(pgrbar + '%');
    $('#step-' + currentStep).hide();
    $('#step-' + prevStep).show();
    $('#step-' + prevStep).removeClass("slideInRight").addClass("slideInLeft");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But I have checked it did not work

Comment: I did not get any error but the next button did not work

Comment: can you check the console for errors? `Ctrl Shift i` and go to console tab

Comment: Hi, I have added your code and its work but the progress bar is not working. only work after I click continue button for that step and also I have added a code below but msg variable does not show on the input field